# Wordpress: control disk space

Tags: wordpress

I'm using single site WP installation.

How to limit the disk space that can be used by my clients for upload media files?

How do I monitor the free disk space?
I want to control it via Database or WP API function, if possible.

Comment: Hi, it's unclear what you mean do you mean the amount of files they can upload as media attachments? Or the size of files?

Comment: Actual server space and usage statistics would be available from your hosting login normally if you have a cPanel or other GUI installed.

Comment: The amount of files they can upload as media attachment. I am running WP from my own hosting server. I don't have cPanel or GUI. I want to control it via Database or WP API function.

Comment: What type of a server are you running? If it's linux + apache you can add a quota. This is not something you would do in WordPress itself.